# I can't tell why my IF statement is producing false result

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-statements

```
=IF(0<VLOOKUP($A9&$E9,'All Orders Avg'!$Q:$S,3,FALSE)<1,1,VLOOKUP($A9&$E9,'All Orders Avg'!$Q:$S,3,FALSE))
```

The IF Statement is supposed to find values between 0 & 1 and round them up to 1, instead it is flagged as FALSE and gives me the actual value of the cell which in this case is 0.25 and therefore should be TRUE and rounded to 1. Both columns are formatted as numbers. Let me know if you need additional details, but I think I am just over looking the formula.

Answer (score 3):

`Value1 < Value2 < Value3` is not valid syntax in Excel, you need to use `AND` :

```
=IF(AND(0<VLOOKUP($A9&$E9,'All Orders Avg'!$Q:$S,3,FALSE), VLOOKUP($A9&$E9,'All Orders Avg'!$Q:$S,3,FALSE)<1),1,VLOOKUP($A9&$E9,'All Orders Avg'!$Q:$S,3,FALSE))
```

You could also use [`ROUNDUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUNDUP-function-F8BC9B23-E795-47DB-8703-DB171D0C42A7) to simplify things a little:

```
=IF(ROUNDUP(VLOOKUP($A9&$E9,'All Orders Avg'!$Q:$S,3,FALSE),0) = 1, 1,VLOOKUP($A9&$E9,'All Orders Avg'!$Q:$S,3,FALSE))
```